# Unexpected behavior due to possible variable aliasing

Tags: python, numpy, immutability

C++ programmer here doing Python. The input `U` to the method `do_something()` changes from `[1.0]` to `[0.0]` upon calling the method `clear()`. Debugging made it clear that the line `self.current *= 0` is the culprit. However, I cannot explain the reason. I'm sure it has something to do with that the variable `U0` is used to initialize the member variable `current`, and used as the first element in the list/argument of the method `do_something`.

```py
import numpy as np

class blah:
    def __init__(self,U0):
        self.current  = np.expand_dims(U0,-1)

    def clear(self):
        self.current *= 0 # <- culprit

    def do_something(self,U):
        print(U)
        self.clear()
        print(U)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    U0 = np.ones(1)
    b = blah(U0)
    b.do_something([U0])
```

Comment: `expand_dims` makes a new array, but it is a `view` of `U0`.  So changes to `self.current` will affect the original `U0`.  Understanding the difference between an array `view` and `copy` is an important part of the `numpy` learning curve.

Comment: Aha... Also, if you change `U0`, `self.current` changes accordingly. How can I get a new array, then?

Comment: Make a copy of the array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

Comment: There's a copy function and method.